# Refactor two similar methods loading data to different classes

Tags: c#

Below are two example Methods, both very similar apart from the 2 class references. ie. one uses FishSettings and FishTileData the other WallSettings and WallTileData.

How can I write a single Method and then call/reference the classes it's been called with? I need a Generic Method right?

```
void Fish(int id, GameObject tile, TileType tileType)
    {
        FishSettings settings = tile.GetComponent<FishSettings>();
        foreach (FishTileData data in DataBase(tileType))
        {
            if (data.Id == id)
            {
                settings.Load(data);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
void Wall(int id, GameObject tile, TileType tileType)
    { 
        WallSettings settings = tile.GetComponent<WallSettings>();
        foreach (WallTileData data in DataBase(tileType))
        {
            if (data.Id == id)
            {
                settings.Load(data);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

void LoadData(GameObject _newTile, TileData _td)
{
    switch (_td.GetTileType())  // This is a virtual Method in the base class : TileData
    {
        case TileType.Fish:
            FishSettings settings = _newTile.GetComponent<FishSettings>();
            settings.Load((FishTileData)_td);
            break;
        case TileType.Wall:
            WallSettings settings = _newTile.GetComponent<WallSettings>();
            settings.Load((WallTileData)_td);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }                
}
```

Comment: how the definition of `Load` looks like?

Comment: Completely unrelated to your current question, but it looks like you're loading "everything" from a database and then manually searching through to find the one item you're interested in. Almost always, it's better to push that search down into the database and to let *it* find the correct item, far more efficiently.

Comment: `if (data.Id = id)` should be `if (data.Id == id)` meaning equals instead of assigning the value?

Comment: I was typing in notepad and missed the ==, good catch lol

Comment: I would love to know how I would, using what little information I've given, change the search to be far more efficient although this current way takes about 2 seconds to load over 3000 tiles? I do however understand how bad it is,

Comment: I added a new Method in the code above called LoadData() that simply (stupid me) takes the correct tile data from file and loses the need for the now redundant Foreach.loops.  Thanks to everyone for their comments. All we're useful in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can merge these two methods into one generic method assuming you can modify all other involved classes to implement some interfaces. You need to make methods with the same name (`Id` and `Load`) to be callable from generic parameter constrained to interface (assuming types has no common parent you can control).

```
interface IHasId { int Id {get;}}
interface ILoadable<TData> { void Load(TData data);}

void LoadItem<TSettings, TData>(int id, GameObject tile, TileType tileType) 
       where : TSettings : ILoadable<TData>, TData : IHasId
{ 
    TSettings  settings = tile.GetComponent<TSettings>();
    foreach (TData data in DataBase(tileType))
    {
        if (data.Id = id)
        {
            settings.Load(data);
            break;
        }
    }
}

class WallSettings : ILoadable<WallTileData>, ...
class WallTileData : IHasId,...
```

and use it like

```
LoadItem<WallSettings, WallTileData>(...);
```

Notes:

- searching through all objects to find item by id looks slow. You may want to provide ID lookup in your `DataBase`
- you may try to use `dynamic` instead of generics if that satisfy your performance goals
- rewriting overall load sequence to create object based on data from storage may be better option.

Answer (score -2):

this looks at first glance like it might be a candidate for an *virtual method* in an *abstract* base class.

```
public abstract class GameObject 
{
    public virtual void LoadSettings(int id)
    {
        var tileType =
            this is Fish? TileType.Fish:
            this is Wall? TileType.Wall: TypeType.Null;
        var settings = 
            this is Fish? tile.GetComponent<FishSettings>():
            this is Wall? tile.GetComponent<WallSettings>():
                          null;

        foreach (var data in DataBase(tileType))
        {
            if (data.Id = id)
            {
                settings.Load(data);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Fish: GameComponent
{
    // rest of Fish class
}
public class Wall: GameComponent
{
    // rest of Wall class
}
```

Comment: What about creating abstract getter Type and Abstract Method GetComponent in your GameObject class and then implement it in Fish/Wall class? In your current solution you would have a lot of ifs